# Pointwise convergence of a sequence of polynomials

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, polynomials, convergence-divergence

Consider the identity function $f(x) = x$ and let $\{h_n;n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a sequence of polynomials, which are defined on $[0,a]$ with some fixed $a<1$, and are of the form $h_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_{i,n} x^i$ where $c_{i,n}$ is the $i$th coefficient in the $n$th polynomial $h_n$. Further assume that:

(1) $0 \leq h_n(x) \leq x$ and $h_n(0) = 0$ for every $n$;

(2) each $h_n$ is monotonically increasing;

(3) $\lim_{n \to \infty} h_n(x) = x$ uniformly for all $x \in [0,a]$.

From (1) we know that $c_{1,n} = h_n'(0) \leq x'|_{x=0} = 1$ for every $n$. My question is: from conditions (1), (2) and (3), is it necessarily true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_{1,n} = 1$? If I impose the extra condition $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{\sum_{i=2}^n |c_{i,n}|\} < M$ for some absolute constant $M > 0$, then the claim holds. But this is a too stringent condition. But I am not sure if the claim is unconditionally true. If not, what could be a minimal set of conditions that I need to impose? Thanks very much.

Comment: You forgot to mention what's the purpose of this, since $x$ _is_ a polynomial. So why don't you just set $h_n(x)=x$?

Comment: @Professor Vector The purpose is that given a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ on some $[a,b]$ that converge uniformly to a function $f$, in general we cannot say anything about how the sequence of derivatives $\{f_n '\}$ behave. So I am considering an example where we can get some result on the sequence of derivatives.

Comment: Well, you've just added more confusion, because in your question, there was no "uniform convergence". Of course, there are examples where the derivatives converge (I gave a trivial one), but you evaded the question of the purpose. It's pointless, imho.

Comment: Ok, fine. The title is misleading. It is not a question on approximation, but a question on convergence. As you said, there are examples where the derivatives converge, and I am constructing this particular one, because the polynomials are "well-behaved", so that I think it should be true that the derivatives converge. But maybe we need certain condition on how the coefficients behave, for example, an upper bound on $c_{i,n}$ in terms of $n$. But I am not sure about this.

Comment: Is there even a non-trivial sequence $h_n$ with the desired properties? It seems to me that (1) will never be satisfied by any polynomial other than $x$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jose27 Thanks for your comment. For example, $x^2$ satisfies condition (1) on $[0,a]$ with $a<1$. I would have added a constraint that these polynomials are defined on $[0,a]$.

Comment: So all the properties need only hold in an interval $[0,a]$, not just the third one?

Comment: @Jose27 Yes, you are right, and this has beed modified. Any idea of whether the claim is true or not? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No.  For $\epsilon>0$, let $d_\epsilon(x)=\epsilon$ for $x\leq\epsilon$, $d_\epsilon(x)=1-\epsilon$ for $x\geq 2\epsilon$, and interpolate linearly on $[\epsilon,2\epsilon]$.  By the Weierstrass approximation theorem, let $p_\epsilon$ be a polynomial that uniformly approximates $d_\epsilon$ within $\epsilon/2$ on $[0,a]$, and let $q_\epsilon$ be the antiderivative of $p_\epsilon$ with $q_\epsilon(0)=0$.  Note that $q_\epsilon$ satisfies your conditions (1) and (2) (since $p_\epsilon$ is always between $\epsilon/2$ and $1-\epsilon/2$), and $q_\epsilon(x)\to x$ uniformly on $[0,a]$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.  However, $q_\epsilon'(0)=p_\epsilon(0)\to 0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.

In particular, then, we can pick a sequence $\epsilon_k\to 0$ for which the polynomials $q_{\epsilon_k}$ have increasing degree, and take them to be a subsequence of your sequence $(h_n)$.  Then $c_{1,n}$ will not converge to $1$ since it converges to $0$ on a subsequence.